# Bind Windows key to xubuntu "Start Menu"

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, menu

Simple problem:

I have a fresh xubuntu installation (16.04.1) on a very old notebook.
Everything works fine now, but I'd like to ***toggle*** the "start menu". (I don't know what it's called in linux sorry :c)

I found several solutions telling me to use shortcuts, tl;dr binding `xfce4-popup-applicationsmenu` to <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> works well to ***open*** the menu.

The problem is, as you may guessed because of my totally not obvious formatting, that I can't close this menu by pressing the same button again.
I remember being able to do so on another (older) Xubuntu installation I had some time ago, not sure though.

Comment: I can't find an easy way to do this. The binary that opens the menu doesn't support toggling at all.

Comment: You want to use the whisker menu or the traditional xfce menu?

Comment: The traditional xcfe menu...

Answer (score 48):

Go to the `Application Shortcuts` tab in the keyboard settings, create a new shortcut and copy the command that is triggered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> (the default shortcut for the Whisker Menu).

As of Xubuntu 16.04, the command you have to enter is `xfce4-popup-whiskermenu`:

[image: screenshot of keyboard settings on Xubuntu 16.04]

Comment: Thank you man, been searching this for more than a minute since installing Xubuntu Desktop.

Comment: Please note that using Super as a standalone shortcut together with Super+? combinations will cause combos to trigger two things, so for instance Super+F will open the file manager and the menu will toggle. Very clunky.

Answer (score 2):

Recent Xubuntu releases use Whisker Menu by default, which is a more capable menu than the Applications Menu, and is what most people use nowadays, so I will describe the way to open this menu, with the deafult settings, by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key. This method doesn't conflict with other shortcuts, as @Rafal G. mentions in [their comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863914/bind-windows-key-to-xubuntu-start-menu#comment2203064_879297), and is the way other distributions, e.g. Manjaro, use the <kbd>Super</kbd> key to open the menu.

What you have to do is bind the default shortcut that opens the Whisker Menu (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>) to the <kbd>Super</kbd> key with [`xcape`](https://github.com/alols/xcape) and have it run at startup. To do this, follow these steps:

1. Install `xcape`:

   ```
   sudo apt install xcape
   ```
2. Open Session and Startup and go to the *Application Autostart* tab.
3. Press the <kbd>+</kbd> button to the lower left of the window to add a new application.

   [image: Session and Startup]
4. In the *Edit application* window that opens, add the *Name* and *Description* (optional) that you prefer and the following *Command*, with *Trigger* set *on login* (also see screenshot):

   ```
   xcape -e 'Super_L=Control_L|Escape'
   ```

   [image: Edit application]
5. Click *OK*.
6. Log out and log in again.

You should now be able to open Whisker Menu by pressing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

**Note:** If you use a shortcut other than <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> to open your menu (it doesn't necessarily have to be the Whisker Menu), just adjust the command in step 4 to use the proper shortcut.